# What is the significance of @Smoke in Robotium? When should it be used?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium, android-testing

I'm new to Robotium and in the `NotePadTest.java` example, I encountered `@Smoke` annotation. What is the purpose of using `@Smoke`? For example, we use `@Override` when we are overriding a method, or `@implements` when we are implementing methods of an interface. My question is why `@Smoke`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reference to [smoke testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Software_development). It should be a set of fast tests that can be run very often to catch any obvious problems early.

Comment: So, should all the test cases have @Smoke annotation?

Comment: I don't really know Robotium, so I'm not sure. There might be a different annotation to use for really slow tests. Otherwise, you should use @Smoke for all your tests.

Answer (score 0):

The Smoke Test is a test which runs a sanity check to see if the project is eligible for other tests or not. Smoke tests are small tests without overhead so we can save time before running other tests.